# How to extend an existing object in c# 4.0 using dynamics

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic

I would like to have something similar to javascript's prototype property in c#.
The idea is to extend an instance of a class like you do in javascript.
The closest thing I found was using ExpandoObject, but you can't initialize it with an existing object.
Another problem is that you can get back the original object from the ExpandoObject.

Here is what I want to do:

```
var originalObject = new Person();
originalObject.name = "Will";
var extendedObject = new ExpandoObject();
extendedObject.lastName = "Smith";

//do something

originalObject = (Person) extendedObject;
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to mix statically and dynamically typed references. You can't do that.

Comment: Related https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Feb/08/Creating-a-dynamic-extensible-C-Expando-Object

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can partially solve the problem using something like:

```
public static class DynamicExtensions
{
    public static dynamic ToDynamic(this object value)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value.GetType()))
            expando.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(value));

        return expando as ExpandoObject;
    }
}
```

But you are not able to copy the methods to the new ExpandoObject

Comment: I actually think this is what I need to add 3 custom fields to my typed Class, but I don't understand how to use it.