# JSON.NET: Define C# field that can hold two different kind of objects

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following objects that I serialize with JSON.NET (not this in particular, but with similar structure).

1. A basic class for request

   ```
   public class Request
   {
       public string version = "1.0";
       public RequestParams params;

       public Request(RequestParams params)
       {
           this.params = params;
       }
   }
   ```
2. A basic payload class

   ```
   public abstract class RequestParams
   { }
   ```
3. Payload classes

   ```
   public SampleRequest : RequestParams
   {
       public string someInfo = "param info";
   }
   ```
4. Usage

   ```
   new Request(new SampleRequest());
   ```

This is all fine when I know the structure of the requests. However, sometimes I need to define dynamic object as "params" parameter. That is, I need to have "params" object be treated as a Dictionary (but without the []), so that I receive JSON in the format:

```
    {
        "version":"1.0",
        "params":{
            "dynamic":"x",
            ...any number of dynamically added fields
            "dynamic2":"y"
        }
    }
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dynamic` and `ExpandoObject`:

```
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.Name = "Name";
parameters.Age = 30;
// Adding as much property as you like dynamically
```

this after serialization becomes:

```
{
    'Name': 'Name',
    'Age': 32,
    /* any other dynamic property */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, from this tip and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651190/how-to-extend-an-existing-object-in-c-sharp-4-0-using-dynamics I managed to come up with a solution - map the RequestParams params when passed to an internal Dictionary :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a base `Request` class that pulls in its information from a `params` dictionary. This is your dynamic request object.

Create classes that inherit from `Request` that operate upon the dictionary, instead of members. These are you 'known' requests.

`params` is a keyword in .Net. Consider using another varaible name.

Comment: Solved it. The params word was for a sample - not an actual code ;)